# Pandas - custom types

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe which I wish to convert the columns to a specific data format. I have a method which coverts the data to various types. My code is currently incomplete as I am unsure of how to iterate throw the column rows and convert the data accordingly.

```
def _get_mappings(mapping_dict):

    json_data = pd.json_normalize(api_response)
    tmp_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()

    for mapping_item in mapping_dict:
        json_data[mapping_item["field"]] = _parse_data_types(json_data["created_time"], mapping_item["type"])

        # Do some other stuff...


def _parse_data_types(pandas_column, field_type):

    # How do I iterate the rows for each column and covert them to the different types
    # as shown below? I may have more return types in the future.

    if field_type == "str":
        field_data = str(field_data)

    elif field_type == "int":
        field_data = int(field_data)

    # Converts 13-digit epoch to a datetime string. It is a str.
    elif field_type == "datetime":
        field_data = epoch_to_datestr(field_data)

    return pandas_column
```

Edited sample data:

```
# Just using list as an example as I am unsure how pandas stores it columns.

input date column: [1589537024000, 1589537025000, 1589537026000]  # epoch as integer
output date column: ["2020-05-15 10:03:44", "2020-05-15 10:03:45", "2020-05-15 10:03:46"]  # string

input kg column: ["123", "456", "789"]  # string
output kg column: [123, 456, 789]  # integers
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Apologies, but I am not clear with what exactly is the issue? Can you explain? Something like Output v/s Expected-Output?

Comment: @Anshul edited to show sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `to_datetime` and `as_type` functions.
Note that the way it is declare, `col2` is first an `object` serie. You then need to convert to datetime first, then convert to int. The direct conversion from `object` to `int` do not work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1589537024000, "2020-05-15 10:03:44"],
                   [1589537025000, "2020-05-15 10:03:45"],
                   [1589537026000, "2020-05-15 10:03:46"]],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2'], dtype=object)
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
df['col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'], unit='ms')
df['col2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col2']).values.astype('int64') // 10 ** 6
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

output:

```
            col1                 col2
0  1589537024000  2020-05-15 10:03:44
1  1589537025000  2020-05-15 10:03:45
2  1589537026000  2020-05-15 10:03:46
col1    object
col2    object
dtype: object
                 col1           col2
0 2020-05-15 10:03:44  1589537024000
1 2020-05-15 10:03:45  1589537025000
2 2020-05-15 10:03:46  1589537026000
col1    datetime64[ns]
col2             int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: I don’t understand, your answer. For column one I want to convert the epoch to the date time str. And for column two I want to convert str to int.

Comment: This is what the code do: the first part define the dataFrame with 2 columns that are declared as `object` type. The function `print(df.dtypes)` shows the datatype of each columns. The second part convert `col1` to datetime using the function `to_datetime` and then convert the `col2` to int using `to_datetime` and `as_type('int64')` function. We finally show the DataFrame values and type. You can see that `col1` type is `datetime64[ns]` and `col2` is `int64`

Comment: After reviewing the to_datetime, I now understand what you did. Thanks!